# Big Query firebase analytics , query last request of customers

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I m working with big query in firebase analytics and I want to know if someone know a query to retrieve a list of last request of each user , with all the data for each customer
, i want ONLY one row for each user , the last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post any data, but in general you can apply a pattern like this:

```
with 
data as (select * from `project.dataset.table`),
rowed as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by session_timestamp desc) as rn
  from data
)
select * except(rn)
from rowed
where rn = 1
```

Keep in mind this selects all the data, which could be potentially very expensive in BQ, so be sure to only select the fields you need/want to answer your specific question.